# UWP ListView DataTemplate Bindings

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

My ViewModel

```
BookingTakerViewModel
```

has a property

```
public List<string> Vias {get;set;}
```

I am wanting to bind a ListView with a DataTemplate but I can not find out how to do it. This is my code and it is throwing this error when it runs:

```
 "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'UI_Test_1.ViewModels.BookingTakerViewModel'."
```

I thought that the x:DataType should reference the class and in this case it is my Viewmodel.I presume that the x:Bind Vias is wrong beacuase this is a List so lost as to what to do.

```
<ListView
    Name="viasList"
    Width="300"
    BorderBrush="Black"
    BorderThickness="5"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind viewModel.Vias, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                  <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="1" />
                   <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="15" />
            </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
               <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="dt" x:DataType="viewmodels:BookingTakerViewModel">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind Vias, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The Vias are intantiated with data so it's not that which is causing a NullReference Exception. I believe the XAML is incorrect.

Comment: some reading for you: http://dotnetpattern.com/wpf-listview-binding

Comment: Thanks that uses binding tho not x:bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for something like this?

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="dt" x:DataType="x:String">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Inside the data template, the context of `{x:Bind}` is the templated object, which is a string item from the collection you set in `ItemsSource`.